# Python REST API gives Internal Server Error

Tags: python, rest, api, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a REST API in python .. I have decent experience in python but relatively new to REST APIs ... When I run my python script I get a "Internal Server Error" on my browser ..

Some thing like this:

[Error on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zScJx.jpg)

and on my console I see this:

[Error as displayed on my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERCpx.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

import firebase_admin

# For connecting to firestore database and authentication
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

# For Data base Connectivity
from firebase_admin import db

from flask import jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

  class Firebase_Data(Resource):


   def getData(self):

       # Setting up credentials to connect
       cred = credentials.Certificate(../Path)

       # Setting up secure connection to firestore Real time database

       app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
           'projectId' : 'project_ID'
       })


       # Connecting to the firestore client
       db_ref = firestore.client()

       # Referring to the '** section of the data
       ref_inc = db_ref.collection(u'name of column')

       # Fetching all the records under that particular section and 
        converting them to list of dictionaries
        docs = list( ref_inc.get() )



      lat_long = []

      for doc in docs:

          data = doc.to_dict()

          lat_long.append(

              { 'Latitude:' : data['latitude'], 'Longitude' : 
               data['longitude'] } )


      return jsonify(lat_long)


api.add_resource(Firebase_Data, '/Firebase_Data') # Route_1

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(port=5002)
```

I'm basically trying to fetch some data from a Fire store database and display it on the browser. I don't think the fire store part has anything to do with my error, I think I'm missing something on executing the "get" function of my python class which I'm not able to figure out .. Any help is highly appreciated.. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to implement a `get` method in your class, not `getData`.

Comment: @KlausD. ... Thank you so much it worked ! I feel so dumb -_- ! lol !